# scan arithmetic operands c and compare them with string

Tags: c, operands

I am trying to `scanf` arithmetical operands into variable. I want to put "+" into variable. I tried everything I have found but nothing has worked so far. The best thing I came with is:

```
char plus = "+";
char* c;
scanf("%c", &c);
if (strcmp(plus, c) == 0) {
    printf("you have + in variable");
```

But this does not work. It seems like "+" does not get into variable `plus` nor does it get scanned into variable using `scanf`. Is there any trick for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple errors in there:

- you declare a char plus and you initialize it with a `char*` (and not a `char`).
- `scanf` with `%c` expects a `char*` but you are providing a `char**`
- you are comparing a `char` with a `char*` in `strcmp`

If you are dealing with single character operators there's no need to do things more complex than they are:

```
char plus = '+';
char c;
scanf("%c",&c);

if(plus == c)
  printf("you have + in variable");
```

Comment: im scanning it alongside number , if i put + <whitespace> 100 into console/scanf the program waits and does nothing ,how can i fix it? to better understanding i have this code if(scanf("%c%d",&c,&last)!=2 || last<0){
        printf("fail\n");
        return 1;
    };
which gets triggered when i put + 100 or - 100 , but when i put jut 100 it does not get triggered...

Comment: ^^^ that is a different question.  Jack has answered your original question  well, and you should accept it.